# How can I merge unversioned MonoDevelop code back into a git repository?

Tags: application-development, git, monodevelop

My group partner and I are creating a MySQL database application with a GTK# frontend. Our application consists of a main window with information displayed in multiple tabs. My partner started most of the implementation, then he gave me a copy of the project folder so I could implement half of the tabs and he could do the other half.

Now we want to merge our work back together, but we weren't using source control (yeah, yeah, I know...) and we aren't sure how to easily smush them back together by hand. His portion of the code is now hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/), and we're wondering how we might use `git` to merge my unversioned code in with his. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered using source control such as Bazaar ;)?

You can still use source control even after developing the project. You would just need to make sure to upload your changes (and pull them in) after he creates the base repository.

Comment: Okay, we're using GitHub now to host our project, but we're still unsure how to merge my code in with his after I pull his with `git clone`. My code is in another folder on my computer at the moment.

Comment: I'm suspecting part of the solution might involve the use of `diff` to generate patches, but I don't think I know enough to make a full solution off of that.

Answer (score 1):

His code, and your code, should share a common origin.

What you need is a git repository with this common origin as a revision.

His code state should use this common origin as a parent, so should yours.

That copy he gave you should do - if you still have an archive of it.

1. Create a new git repo
2. Copy the origin code into it
3. Add and commit
4. Now create and check out a new branch for his code (`git checkout -b his-code`)
5. Delete all the origin code, put his new code in
6. Add and commit
7. Check out the origin code again (`git checkout master`)
8. Make a new branch for YOUR code (`git checkout -b my-code`)
9. Delete the origin code, put in your code
10. Add and commit

Now you have a repository with the history of both your changes from a common origin. Merging these two branches should produce the desired result.

```
git checkout master
git merge his-code
git merge my-code
```

Comment: By "origin code", you mean the initial code he wrote that I'm trying to merge my unversioned stuff back into?

Comment: Yup, the initial archive of code that he sent you. This is the last known common revision that you both had at one point. I don't mean the Git convention of calling the branch you cloned "origin" (sorry for confusion),

Comment: At Step 6, I run into a problem with `git` where `git add .` runs without output, but subsequently running `git commit` just tells me there are no changes to commit. Is there a way to force a commit without changes? Because the code from Step 5 is the same code as from Step 2.

Comment: Okay, I got past that by just doing a `touch junk.txt` so that there would be a negligible difference and allow me to do the commit. However, when I open the project up in MonoDevelop, my stuff's there but not his.

Comment: If his new code in step 5 is the same as the original code in step 2, then he has made no changes since he gave you the code. Therefore your code should already represent the complete merged code. As long as it's true that he hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Well, no. The problem is that I split my code off of his, then he made his tabs and I made mine. Then he hosted his code on GitHub, and now I'm trying to merge my changes in with his without undoing his work.

Comment: Are you sure that step 2 is the code as he initially provided it to you, and that step 5 is his code as it is now?